# iText: Splitting pdf documents in a Multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, io, itext

I am using iText2.1.2 but also found the same behaviour on iText5.4.3.

I have a requirement of breaking 'n' paged document to 'n' documents in my JAX-WS service. I have written the below logic to achieve the same.

```
reader = new PdfReader(fileLocation + "\\" + pdfFilename + ".pdf");
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
int i = 0;

while (i < n) {
    .
    .
    .
    document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    writer = new PdfCopy(document, fos);
    document.open();
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, ++i);
    writer.addPage(page);

    document.close();
    writer.close();
    fos.close();
    .
    .
    .
 }
 reader.close();
```

This also runs in a multi threaded environment. The entire processing is slowing down and makes my service appear sequential because of the following lines.

```
    writer = new PdfCopy(document, fos);
    document.open();
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, ++i);
    writer.addPage(page);
```

**Observation in my service:** For a 500 page document, for 5 threads, each thread is taking around 160 seconds. If the above lines are commented,  then each thread is taking 30 seconds.

I would like to know if this is an expected behaviour and how does iText support for multithreaded enviroments for IO Operations.

Please suggest if any other way is possible to split the 'n' paged document to 'n' documents.

Comment: First of all I don't know your specific documents. Depending on their structure page extraction may take some time. Furthermore, do the parallel threads split the *same* PDF document or *distinct* ones?

Comment: Different threads split different PDFs and also write it into different locations. What are the specific details that u need? Please let me know...

Comment: *What are the specific details that u need?* - to tell whether your delays are to be expected of not I'd need a representative sample pdf giving rise to those delays to be able to reproduce (or not reproduce) your delays.